# How to generate a copy of a google slide programmatically on a recurring basis?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a slide under `URL:https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1IGsd`which is a source slide and cannot be "touched". Now, I want to programmatically make a copy of this source slide every week and save it under the name "slide_{timestamp}"
in my root google drive folder to do manipulations on those.

Can someone help on how to approach this or existing code which may help?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your **source** slide, click on **Tools** => **Script** editor and copy-paste the following function:

```
function copySourceSlide() { 
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  DriveApp.getFileById(presentation.getId()).makeCopy(`slide_${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, destFolder);
}
```

This code will create a copy of the source slide with a name `slide_datetime` to a particular folder of your choice, indicated by `folderId`.

If you want to create a weekly trigger event for a particular day and hour, you can do it either manually or programmatically like that:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {

  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('copySourceSlide')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

References:

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)